# ThreadPoolExecutor or multi-processing for Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Asuume there will be a mega size dataframe, which has > **1M** columns. Based on the following toy dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from concurrent.futures import *
import multiprocessing
num_processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
print(f'num_precesses: {num_processes}')

def ReplaceItem(old_item, input_list, new_item = 'ham'):
    output = []
    for item in input_list:
        if item == old_item:
            output.append(new_item)
        else:
            output.append(item)
    return output


food = pd.DataFrame({'customer':range(1,4),
                     'original':[['egg', 'berry', 'pork', 'tea'],
                                 ['chicken', 'beef', 'water', 'soda'],
                                 ['fish', 'chicken', 'pork', 'coffee']]})

replace_items = {'list1':'egg', 'list2':'chicken', 'list3':'fish'}

food

num_precesses: 10

customer    original
0   1   [egg, berry, pork, tea]
1   2   [chicken, beef, water, soda]
2   3   [fish, chicken, pork, coffee]
```

The goal is to create a new dataframe which have update columns that replace items on the replace_items list with a NEW item 'ham'. The final table should be like below

```
change_items, item_dict = [], dict()

for i in range(len(replace_items.values())):
    change_items.append((list(replace_items.keys())[i],
                         food['original'].apply(lambda x: ReplaceItem(list(replace_items.values())[i], x))))          
    item_dict.update(change_items)
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(item_dict)
    update_df = pd.concat([food, new_df], axis = 1)

update_df
    customer    original                list1                           list2   list3
0   1   [egg, berry, pork, tea]         [ham, berry, pork, tea]         [egg, berry, pork, tea]     [egg, berry, pork, tea]
1   2   [chicken, beef, water, soda]    [chicken, beef, water, soda]    [ham, beef, water, soda]    [chicken, beef, water, soda]
2   3   [fish, chicken, pork, coffee]   [fish, chicken, pork, coffee]   [fish, ham, pork, coffee]   [ham, chicken, pork, coffee]
```

I try to use multi-threading or multi-processing to speed up the whole process but don't know how to implement it correctly. Here, each new column indicates any of rows that have been replaced by a new item. Any suggestions? many thanks in advance

Comment: How many _rows_ does the datarframe (here `food`) have and how long can the lists be?

Comment: @Timus, there are approximate 3M rows in the real dataframe

Comment: And how long can the lists be?

Comment: So the shape of the final dataframe is approximate (3M, 1.5M). It is very huge. The row represents a customer & a column represent an old item is replaced by a new item: 'ham' (if the specific old item appears in any of rows.)